# How to drop buffered websocket messages in aiohttp?

Tags: websocket, aiohttp

It takes my app more time to handle certain messages from a websocket than I have before the next ones come. When the code returns from the handling function I want to read only the newest message. How do I do that in aiohttp?

Comment: How about caching each message as you receive it (but not process it) and only process the cached message once there's no more messages in the buffer? Perhaps sharing some more details about your case would help ...

Comment: @IonutTicus I have multiple websockets opened and any message from any of them can trigger processing longer than await time for new messages in all of opened websockets. I don't see how doubling aiohttp's reception buffer would work here, because I still have to await on the receive() method to pop queued messages one by one an each await can switch to other websockets' receive() method handling. I need something like receive_last() method to drop queued messages save the last/newest one.